# How to load a xib file as a custom class?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm trying to use a xib file to create a reusable component (multiple times in the same View), and everything was fine until i wanted to update some controls from an `@IBInspectable` property. I found that `@IBOutlet`'s are not set at that moment, so i did a search and found something

http://justabeech.com/2014/07/27/xcode-6-live-rendering-from-nib/

He is saving a the loaded view into proxyView so you could use it in the `@IBInspectable`. Unfortunately that code is a bit old and doesn't work as is. But my problem is when i try to load the nib as a class it doesn't work. It only works if i load it as `UIView`.

This line fails as this

```
return bundle.loadNibNamed("test", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? ValidationTextField
```

It only works when is like this

```
return bundle.loadNibNamed("test", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? UIView
```

I think that the problem is, the xib file's owner is marked as `ValidationTextField`, but the main view it's `UIView`. So when you load  the nib it brings that `UIView`, that obviously has no custom properties or outlets.

Many examples about loading xib files say that the class must be in the file owner. So i don't know how to get the custom class using that.

```swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ValidationTextField: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var lblError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var txtField: XTextField!
    @IBOutlet var imgWarning: UIImageView!
    private var proxyView: ValidationTextField?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)!
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        xibSetup()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        xibSetup()
        self.proxyView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }
    func xibSetup() {
        guard let view = loadNib() else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        // Saving the view in a variable
        self.proxyView = view
    }
    func loadNib() -> ValidationTextField? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        return bundle.loadNibNamed("test", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? ValidationTextField
    }
    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 14.0 {
        didSet {
            let font = UIFont(name: "System", size: self.fontSize)
            self.proxyView!.txtField.font = font
            self.proxyView!.lblError.font = font
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know if the rest will work. If what the link says it's true, getting the view after loading the nib will let me access to the outlets.

Running that code fails at this line

```
guard let view = loadNib() else { return }
```

I guess that it can't convert the `UIView` to the class so it returns nil, and then exits.

My goal is to have a reusable component that can be placed many times in a single controller. And be able to see its design in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `xibSetup()` to your initializers. `awakeFromNib` is called too late and it won't be called if the view is created programatically. There is no need to call it in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`.

In short, this can be generalized to:

```
open class NibLoadableView: UIView {
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNibContentView()
        commonInit()
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        loadNibContentView()
        commonInit()
    }

    public func commonInit() {
       // to be overriden
    }
}

public extension UIView {
    // @objc makes it possible to override the property
    @objc
    var nibBundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    }

    // @objc makes it possible to override the property
    @objc
    var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }

    @discardableResult
    func loadNibContentView() -> UIView? {
        guard
            // note that owner = self !!!
            let views = nibBundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil),
            let contentView = views.first as? UIView
        else {
            return nil
        }

        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.frame = self.bounds

        return contentView
    }
}
```

Note that the view that loads the nib must be the **owner** of the view.

Then your class will become:

```
@IBDesignable
class ValidationTextField: NibLoadableView {
    @IBOutlet var lblError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var txtField: XTextField!
    @IBOutlet var imgWarning: UIImageView!

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }

    override func commonInit() {
        super.commonInit()
        updateFont()
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 14.0 {
        didSet {
            updateFont()
        }
    }

    private func updateFont() {
       let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
       txtField.font = font
       lblError.font = font
    }
}
```

I guess that the whole idea about a proxy object comes from misuse of the Nib owner. With a proxy object, the hierarchy would have to be something like this:

```
ValidationTextField
    -> ValidationTextField (root view of the nib)
          -> txtField, lblError, imgWarning
```

which does not make much sense. What we really want is:

```
ValidationTextField (nib owner)
    -> UIView (root view of the nib)
          -> txtField, lblError, imgWarning
```

Comment: Nvm, it works perfectly. Thank you! So the important thing was loading the nib in the init functions. I wish they had something like UserControls in .net, so much easier to use and understand.

Comment: @dpaladin The important thing is to understand how a nib is loaded, what is its owner and stop using that crazy proxy objects :)